# Politics: singular or plural?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is correct, "politics *is* out of scope" or  "politics *are* out of scope?"

Comment: Related (and more broad): [What is the difference between a “singular noun” and a “plural noun treated as singular”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/)

Comment: Related: [“The news is good.” Why?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4146)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct form is:

> Politics is out of scope.

*Politics*, like *mathematics*, *linguistics*, *economics*, and other domains ending in -*ics*, is syntactically singular.

Comment: By itself, when referring to the academic topic of politics, *politics* is singular, but when referring to political affairs or opinions it is plural: *office politics*, *Iranian politics*, *her politics*, etc.

Comment: To provide an example for @nohat's excellent comment:  "I used to enjoy coming to work, but office politics are wearing me down."

Comment: @oosterwal Not only a good example, but a true one! ;)

Comment: I don't get this. If I have 1 politic and then buy another politic, does that equal 2 politics?