# "The news is good." Why?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

We use "the news is good" instead of "the news are good."

What is the rationale behind this? Are there similar situations in English?

Comment: What do you mean by "like this"? And for what exactly are you asking a rationale?

Comment: If by _like this_ you mean words that are plural but treated as singular, then the answer is yes; there are other plural words that are treated (or generally treated) as singular: mathematics and  physics, for example.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Why do you say that "mathematics" and "physics" are plural?

Comment: I'm told that on one particularly dull day between the wars the BBC news bulletin consisted of the following announcement..."Good evening. Here are the news. Tonight, there are no news. Instead, here is a string quartet." I haven't been able to confirm this with Google, though.

Comment: The NOAD reports that mathematics is _plural noun [usually treated as singular];_ the same is reported for _physics._

Comment: @kiamlaluno You may have seen this already, but if not see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/what-is-the-difference-between-a-singular-noun-and-a-plural-noun-treated-as-s) where it turns out that calling "mathematics" and "physics" plural nouns isn't really an uncontroversial categorization.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*News* is uncountable and is used with singular verbs. The *-s* is there because etymologically, it used to be a plural form. Etymonline [says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=news&searchmode=none):

> late 14c., plural of *new* (n.) "new thing," from *new* (adj.), q.v.; after Fr. *nouvelles*, used in Bible translations to render M.L. *nova* (neut. pl.) "news," lit. "new things." Sometimes still regarded as plural, 17c.-19c.

As to other nouns like this, I have looked through a number of Wiktionary and Wikipedia categories, and the closest I could come to similar examples is *measles* and *billiards*.

Yet another interesting (but not really similar) case is *species*. Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural):

> *Specie* and *species* make a fascinating case. Both words come from a Latin word meaning "kind", but they do not form a singular-plural pair. In Latin, *specie* is the ablative singular form, while *species* is the nominative form, which happens to be the same in both singular and plural. In English, *species* behaves similarly—as a noun with identical singular and plural—while *specie* is treated as a mass noun, referring to money in the form of coins (the idea is of "[payment] in kind").

Comment: What do you mean by "other nouns like this"?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I mean nouns where the singular form suspiciously looks as if it were plural, as in "bad news is good news" or "billiards is fun".

Comment: Also *headquarters* and *shambles*.

Comment: Some dictionaries suggest that "nuptials" is, or can be, singular.