# Pluralisation of sports teams in British and American English

Tags: american-english, british-english, sports

Why do British and American English differ in this respect:

British

> Southampton **are** eyeing up a ready-made replacement for Luke Shaw

American

> Southampton **is** eyeing up a ready-made replacement for Luke Shaw

American sports journalism differs in their reference to teams. The American style is to treat the team as singular, whereas the British use plurals.

What are the rules in other variants of English (Aus, NZ etc.)?

Comment: Be careful ever to ask _why_ when discussing (a) language ;)

Comment: Hasn't this been answered before? It's a well-known fact that UK English uses plurals for aggregate human nouns, where American English uses singulars: _Congress has/Parliament have decided, Chicago has/Manchester have taken the field_. As for _why,_ nobody knows, any more than they know "why" UK English is non-rhotic, while American is rhotic. That's just the way it evolved.

Comment: ... You don't drink enough tea.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12818/which-is-correct-all-the-media-is-or-all-the-media-are/12827#12827

Answer (score 4):

There is the common difference around collective nouns between American and British usage, but there is something interesting about this case in particular. American team names often (with very few exceptions) have a plural nick name which people refer to using plurals. So, Americans will say

> The Yankees win

but

> New York wins

Even though "Yankees" and "New York" refer to the same club. So, Americans distinguish between *the team* and *the members on the team* and change pluralization accordingly.

Comment: And even when the nickname is singular (*the Jazz, the Magic*), it often takes a plural verb.