# Can we use singular or plural nouns with names of countries?

Tags: verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

When asked a question about Collective Nouns, I told them that it is all right to use a singular or plural verb after a Collective Noun, as in -

- *The class **was*** listening to the lecture with rapt attention.

Here the class is taken as a whole.

- *The class **were*** working on their projects.

Here the the individuals are taken into consideration rather than the class as a whole.

Now the question is: Do we use singular or plural verbs with the names of countries, which are proper nouns, for the same reason?

As in:

- *Bhutan **is*** said to be The Last Shangrila.
- *Bhutan **are*** working on promoting their GNH Philosophy.

Comment: In American English, principally the mass noun sense. In BrE, it varies, but they're more accommodating of the count noun sense.

Comment: With a country, treat it as singular.  With a sports team, treat it as plural, eg *"Bhutan are going through to the final, against all expectations"*

Comment: @DanBron, what do you mean "mass noun sense"? The question makes no mention of mass nouns.

Comment: @Silenus Is Bhutan a singular entity or a collection of individuals, is what I'm driving at.

Comment: @DanBron, Gotcha, but in either case, it's not a mass noun. It's a difference between the *ensemble* reading of a collective noun (individuals taken as a singular entity) and the *individual* reading of a collective noun (individuals taken one by one). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun

Comment: Duplicate of [Can the name of a country be considered a plural noun, as a collective of e.g. its citizens?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183003/can-the-name-of-a-country-be-considered-a-plural-noun-as-a-collective-of-e-g-i?s=2|0.3132) and [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

Comment: Even Brits do not say: Bhutan ARE. They say: The US are, yes.

Comment: @Lambie I'd use _Bhutan are_ / _The US are_ for a football etc team, and _Bhutan is_ / _The US is getting more expensive to visit_ etc.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Well, I disagree. Not always: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page51.shtml

Comment: @Lambie You disagree with what I say I say? It's your comment 'Even Brits do not say: Bhutan ARE. They say: The US are, yes.' that's very dubious. Most Brits would use 'Bhutan / The US are winning at half time' but 'Bhutan / The US is easy to reach by plane nowadays'. Which is totally in line with what Karen Adams says in your linked article..

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Apologies. I should have been clearer. Bhutan is a small country versus Bhutan are not planning an  invasion of Nepal is the kind of difference I should have made and did not. SORRY.