# Do I use "has" or "have" when talking about a sports team?

Tags: grammar

For example, if I want to talk about a team's chances of winning a competition, which of these would be correct?

What do I say?

> United *have* the best chance of winning.
>   United *has* the best chance of winning.

The team is made up of many players so I think it should be plural; therefore, I think *have* sounds correct. But someone told me it should be *has* as the team is just one thing.

Comment: The duplicate question certainly answers the OP questions but for somebody who is not a native speaker, the answer is not clear. In brevis, it depends on the speaker. If he or she is BrEng, the word *team* might be considered singular or plural. Singular if I think of a team as being a collective whole, plural if I think of the players that make up a team. An AmEng speaker will usually interpret "team" as being singular.

Comment: related:['Team of economists': singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217357/team-of-economists-singular-or-plural) and [Pluralisation of sports teams in British and American English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166773/pluralisation-of-sports-teams-in-british-and-american-english)