# When should I use "is" and when "are"?

Tags: present-tense

Which of these are correct?

1. All I see **is** iPhones.
2. All I see **are** iPhones.

I've seen Rihanna wrote: All I see **is** Signs. Some people use are like: All I see **are** Cliffs.

Could someone explain when to use "is" and when "are"?

Comment: Related: [Which is correct: “All the media is” or “all the media are”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12818/which-is-correct-all-the-media-is-or-all-the-media-are)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2006/12/all-is-vs-all-are.html

According to the link above :

> “All” is a two-faced word. It can be either singular (“is”) or plural
>   (“are”). If a writer means “all of it,” she should use “is.” If she
>   means “all of them,” she should go with “are.” So it depends on
>   whether your contributor was thinking of the whole dish or the various
>   things in it: “All [the soup] is returned to a simmer” or “All [the
>   ingredients] are returned to a simmer.”

Also in this forum: https://www.englishforums.com/English/AllIsOrAllAre/zdngg/post.htm

there was an interesting comment:

> Meanwhile, I'll add that "all" is sometimes used to mean "the only
>   thing". For example:
>
> - All I want is you.
>
> However, even if the "only thing" actually consists of more than one
>   thing, we frequently use the singular form of the verb . For example:
>
> - All I want for Christmas is my two front teeth.

I would also say that don't really check songs lyrics for grammar mistakes, because they sometimes use broken English in writing the lyrics!

Hope it helps you

Comment: English has a rule making the verb agree with the subject, but no rule for agreement with predicate nouns. If _teeth_ is plural, no problem; but it's not the subject, so the verb doesn't show it.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: All I see ARE iPhones

Long Answer:
The subject of your sentence is "all".

> All I see is/are iPhones.

All is an indefinite pronoun, and can be both singular and plural.

> For indefinite pronouns that can be singular or plural, it depends on what the indefinite pronoun refers to.
>
> Correct: All of the people clapped their hands. 
>   (All refers to people, which is plural.)
>
> Correct: All of the newspaper was soaked. 
>   (Here all refers to newspaper, which is singular.)

[Source](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000027.htm)

However, in this case, it's clear that "All" refers to the multiple iPhones that Rihanna sees, so "All" should be used plurally.

Comment: But i thought All here refers to i

Comment: Not necessarily. As Kian points out, "All I want for Christmas is my two front teeth." is the idiomatic choice. 'All' may be read as 'The sum total' here, which would take singular agreement.