# News - Singular or Plural

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“The news is good.” Why?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/the-news-is-good-why)

Does one ask "What are the news" or "What is the news"? Or are both correct in different situations?

Comment: @Jonathan - You're right, it is.  Should've looked before answering...

Comment: @MT_Head: I only noticed the x-ref in the 'related' list after writing my answer, too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very strange: every etymology I find for [**news**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/news) shows it originating as a plural:

> from Middle English *newes*,  plural of
>   *newe*  new ( adj ) on model of Old
>   French *noveles*  or Medieval Latin *nova*
>   new things

and yet it certainly isn't used as one now.

You can't have **a new**; the singular would be **a news item**, **a piece of news**, **a story**, **a scoop**...

You can refer to **the new** as an abstract, but that's a synonym for "that which is new":

> ...and this he apprehended would be
>   particularly felt whenever the time
>   arrived for exchanging the old for the
>   new.
>   *[The Parliamentary debates from the year 1803 to the present time, Volume 34](http://books.google.com/books?id=5FpFAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22the%20old%20for%20the%20new%22&pg=PT519#v=onepage&q=%22the%20old%20for%20the%20new%22&f=false)*

And of course you can [**begin anew**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anew), but that simply means "start again".

Answer (score 1):

I think the form "What are the news?" is wrong; even though the the word 'news' is plural, it is more of a mass noun (or non-countable noun) than a countable noun (like gold is a mass noun).

Therefore, to my ears, you have to say "What is the news?", treating it as singular (even though it looks singularly like a plural).