# Is "robotics" a plural noun?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Politics: singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/politics-singular-or-plural)
>   [What is the difference between a “singular noun” and a “plural noun treated as singular”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/what-is-the-difference-between-a-singular-noun-and-a-plural-noun-treated-as-si)

Which is the correct form, "Robotics **is** no longer […]," "Robotics **are** no longer […]," or "Robotic **is** no longer […]"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Robotics**, although it's a plural noun, is treated as a singular noun.

See terms like *Linguistics*, *Statistics* or *Economics*, just to name a few.

Robotic can't be used, because it's an **adjective**, not a noun (like Robotics), so:

> Robotics is no longer [...]

Answer (score 5):

If you're using it as the field of study it is singular.

> Robotics is my life.

If you're using it to refer to the components of a robot then it is plural.

> The robotics are defective.