# I have read at some very good forums with impeccable liguistic records - using politics with a plural verb

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

Office politics are real, and dangerous. Just as there is likely merit to the judgements of those who judge colleagues harshly — so is it true that power politics in organizations can cause organizational drag, dumb down decisions, and damage careers. My point is that it is your response to both perceived and real machinations that either amplifies or moderates these dysfunctions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Politics: singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/politics-singular-or-plural) See nohat's comment (which really should be referenced and then the accepted answer). / This question lacks any signs of research (other than anecdotal and one example). Is there no dictionary addressing this? ... Yes.  [AHD and Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/politics) deal with this thoroughly.

Comment: There is no actual question here. But I'm going to assume that @user267542 thinks that *politics* should be singular and is asking about that.

Comment: Politics is what we do to avoid having civil wars.  This is a singular use. Beyond that, the concepts and issues raised in the post would seem to be a better fit on politics.stackexhange.com.